# Create picture in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I want to create following picture using LaTeX. Please help

[image]

Comment: 1 downvote is enough, people! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}    
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[%
    ,every cell/.append style={align=center}
    ,every arrow/.append style={Rightarrow}
    ]
(B)\drar & & & & (HK)\\
& (RL)\rar & (BR)\rar & (M)\urar\drar & \\
(R)\urar & & & & (P)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]